# How to prove $v_1v_2^Tv_2=v_2v_2^Tv_1$?

Tags: matrices, vectors

How can I prove 
$$
v_1v_2^Tv_2=v_2v_2^Tv_1
$$
where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are all of shape $(1, n)$.
The original problem is from [this paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SkxXCi0qFX), where Eq.4 in page 3 is defined as
[image]
But I derive something like 
$$
\alpha R(\tau')\nabla_{\theta'}\log\pi_{\theta'}(\tau')(R(\tau)\nabla_\theta\log\pi_\theta(\tau)^T\nabla_\theta\log\pi_\theta(\tau))
$$
where $\alpha$, $R(\tau')$ and $R(\tau)$ are scalars. In fact I'm not so sure why I transpose the first $\nabla_\theta\log\pi_\theta(\tau)$, I do so simply because I think there should be a matrix. I hope someone could help me clarify it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Err... the OP wants to prove $v_1v_2^Tv_2=v_2v_2^Tv_1$, not $v_1v_2^Tv_2=v_2^Tv_2v_1$.

Comment: If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, this can't be true because the first is a scalar multiple of $v_1$ but the second is a scalar multiple of $v_2$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I think $v_2v_2^T\ne v_2^Tv_2$, the former is a scalar but the later is a matrix of shape $(n, n)$.

Comment: @Maybe Yes, I see the mistake. I don't think the equality is true in that case.

Comment: Thank all of you, I finally found where I made a mistake. I've changed my question

Comment: You really shouldn’t edit your question to change it to something else entirely when someone’s already answered the original. Post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in general not true that $v_1 v_2^T v_2 = v_2 v_2^T v_1$. Try for example with $v_1 =(1,0,0), v_2=(0,0,1)$.